# Kendo UI - the name 'JobList' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im getting an error `the name 'JobList' does not exist in the current context`  where i try to populate the kendo Grid. My views JavaScript code was Like :

```
    var GridName = "#DetailsGrid2_" + MS_MasId;
    var JobList = [];
    var data = $(GridName).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        JobList.push(data[i].JobId);
    }


    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: { 
                url: '@Url.Action("GetJobs", "Jobs", new { JobId = JobList})',
                contentType: "application/json",                    
            },              

        ........
```

I just wanna pass the arrays `JobList` to the MVC Controller and i cannot do that. so please check my code and correct me.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is server side code that parsed before its sent to the view `JobList` is a javascript variable, then it does not even exist at that point.

Comment: `JobList` is a JavaScript Array Elements of JobID. and i just wanna pass that to my Controller. which was like : `public JsonResult GetJobs(int[] JobId).......`

Comment: The either manually build the url - `.../GetJobs?JobID=1&JobID=2&JobID=3` or use the `data:` option of `read` (in which case it will be just `url: '@Url.Action("GetJobs", "Jobs")',`

Comment: i tried with `data` option but it just sending `null` values.

Comment: Then you obviously did it wrong :)

Comment: So, Can you Please correct my code brother ?

Comment: I have already shown you 2 options my previous comments. And how can I correct your code using `data:` when you have not even shown it.

Comment: thanks bro. i found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
           read: function(options) {
              $.ajax({   
                url: '@Url.Action("GetJobs", "Jobs")',
                contentType: "application/json",    
                data : JSON.stringify({JobId : JobList}),
                Type : "POST",
                async : true,
                traditional : true
            });
            },   
    ...............
```

Ref : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource

Answer (score 0):

> Im getting an error the name 'JobList' does not exist in the current context

And Also taking Stephen's comment into consideration

> @Url.Action() is server side code that parsed before its sent to the view JobList is a javascript variable, then it does not even exist at that point.

So what you can do to your existing code is create a Json in your c# code in the views. Like below

```
 @{
   var JobListJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JobList);
  }
```

Then in your javascript block you can create a variable by reading the data from this c# variable, Like below

```
 var jobList = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(JobListJson)));
```

Now you have a jquery variable with your array data.

Note: You would have to use Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget for this.